# Suppressing default anchor behavior in Safari with jQuery

Tags: jquery, safari, jquery-events

I am attempting to prevent default anchor behavior in Safari using the jQuery library.  Unfortunately, the standard techniques of returning false or using `event.preventDefault()` do not seem to be working in Safari.

Could anyone help me with this issue?

The code I'm working with is like this:

```
$('#main .green-tabs a').live("click",function(event){
                    $('.green-tabs a').removeClass('active');
                    $(this).addClass('active');
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var that = this;
                    return LolPage(event,that);});
```

Comment: What happens when you try "bind" instead of "live"?

Comment: I will try that and see if it has an effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the handler return `false` works for me in Safari and FF and Chrome.  See my test page here: http://gutfullofbeer.net/bind.html and it also works if I have the handlers call "preventDefault" instead of just returning false.

The "LolPage" function is left out of your question, and I have to wonder whether that might be of great importance here.

Comment: Hi Pointy,  that function always returns false and does not error out.  I should also mention that this application lives in the facebook environment which I think might be the culprit for some strange reason.  I am going to run a few tests in that environment and will post my results here.

Comment: OK, well good luck!  Mysterious problems like this are always interesting.

Comment: Well it's been a long time but I remember what I traced it down to.  Safari is quite prickly about who gets to set cookies in a framed website (a-la Facebook Iframed applications.)  It requires a user to "explicitly" browse to a domain to set a cookie for that domain.  In that code above a cookie was being lost, which when my request was sent to the server, triggered some Facebook authentication code to return a framebuster instead of the html I was expecting, which made me think the anchor was merely doing its default behavior when in reality I was getting framebusted!  Ha!

Comment: The fix was a client side redirect to the actual domain of the app, set a cookie, then redirecting back to the facebook proxied domain, where subsequent AJAX requests did not framebust since the user had "browsed" to the domain.